# Chances of Push ID duplication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know, I know. The push ID is very unique and have a very least chance of duplicating another node.

But I'm curious, is there a chance that the unique ID will have a duplicated one, if so, does it generate another unique ID and so on?

I know this is kind of a dumb question, but I'm just curious.

Comment: The answer below is not true.  There is an astronomically small chance that two clients could generate a push ID at the same exact period of time with the same exact randomness.  Yes, the push ID is based on time, but two events could happen within the same millisecond.  Also, push IDs are generated entirely on the client without consultation with the server.  All that said, no one has ever reported a problem with push IDs colliding as you're suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO ! Push id generate Unique ID everytime and it's Uniqueness can be guaranteed because firebase generates Unique ID using many Unique paramaters such as TIME. Time will be unique every mili second So does you Unique id, And its not always time but there are many deciding factors internally which ensures the uniqueness. So there will me not a chance that it can generate Duplicate UID, Even if somehow we forcefully make it happen it will be again unique next time.